# python 2.7:iterate dictionary and map values to a file

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

**I have a list of dictionaries which I build from .xml file**:

```
list_1=[{'lat': '00.6849879', 'phone': '+3002201600', 'amenity': 'restaurant', 'lon': '00.2855850', 'name': 'Telegraf'},{'lat': '00.6850230', 'addr:housenumber': '6', 'lon': '00.2844493', 'addr:city': 'XXX', 'addr:street': 'YYY.'},{'lat': '00.6860304', 'crossing': 'traffic_signals', 'lon': '00.2861978', 'highway': 'crossing'}]
```

**My aim is to build a text file with values (not keys) in such order**:
lat,lon,'addr:street','addr:housenumber','addr:city','amenity','crossing' etc...

```
00.6849879,00.2855850, , , ,restaurant, ,'\n'00.6850230,00.2844493,YYY,6,XXX, , ,'\n'00.6860304,00.2861978, , , , ,traffic_signals,'\n'
```

if value not exists there should be empty space.

---

I tried to loop with for loop:

```
for i in list_1:
    line= i['lat'],i['lon'] 
    print line
```

Problem occurs if I add value which does not exist in some cases:

```
for i in list_1:
    line= i['lat'],i['lon'],i['phone']
    print line
```

Also tried to loop and use map() function, but results seems not correct:

```
for i in list_1:
    line=map(lambda x1,x2:x1+','+x2+'\n',i['lat'],i['lon'])
    print line
```

Also tried:

```
 for i in list_1:
    for k,v in i.items():
        if k=='addr:housenumber':
        print v
```

This time I think there might be too many if/else conditions to write.

---

**Seems like solutions is somewhere close. But can't figure out the solution and its optimal way.**

Comment: use dict.get method.

Comment: Have you looked at [**`csv.DictWriter`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)?

Answer (score 0):

I would look to use the `csv` module, in particular `DictWriter`. The `fieldnames` dictate the order in which the dictionary information is written out. Actually writing the header is optional:

```
import csv
fields = ['lat','lon','addr:street','addr:housenumber','addr:city','amenity','crossing',...]
with open('<file>', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fields)
    #writer.writeheader()   # If you want a header
    writer.writerows(list_1)
```

If you really didn't want to use `csv` module then you can simple iterate over the list of the fields you want in the order you want them:

```
fields = ['lat','lon','addr:street','addr:housenumber','addr:city','amenity','crossing',...]
for row in line_1:
    print(','.join(row.get(field, '') for field in fields))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't or don't want to use csv you can do something like

```
order = ['lat','lon','addr:street','addr:housenumber',
         'addr:city','amenity','crossing']
for entry in list_1:
  f.write(", ".join([entry.get(x, "") for x in order]) + "\n")
```

This will create a list with the values from the `entry` map in the order present in the `order` list, and default to `""` if the value is not present in the map.

If your output is a csv file, I strongly recommend using the csv module because it will also escape values correctly and other csv file specific things that we don't think about right now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys
I found the solution. Maybe it is not so elegant but it works.
I made a list of node keys look for them in another list and get values.

```
key_list=['lat','lon','addr:street','addr:housenumber','amenity','source','name','operator']
list=[{'lat': '00.6849879', 'phone': '+3002201600', 'amenity': 'restaurant', 'lon': '00.2855850', 'name': 'Telegraf'},{'lat': '00.6850230', 'addr:housenumber': '6', 'lon': '00.2844493', 'addr:city': 'XXX', 'addr:street': 'YYY.'},{'lat': '00.6860304', 'crossing': 'traffic_signals', 'lon': '00.2861978', 'highway': 'crossing'}]
```

---

**Solution**:

```
    final_list=[]
    for i in list:
    line=str()
        for ii in key_list:     
            if ii in i:         
                x=ii            
                line=line+str(i[x])+','         
            else:           
                line=line+' '+','           
        final_list.append(line)
```